# How do I change the colour of a line between certain values on a matplot graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
line = plt.plot(r, Vr)   
plt.xlabel('r')
plt.ylabel('V(r)')
plt.xlim((0.5,3.5))
plt.ylim((-1.5,2))
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

This is my current code, my line for Vr has lots of data points and I'm trying to change the colour for Vr >= 0 to red and Vr < 0 to green.

I've tried using a when and for argument after the original plot line to see if I can change part of the line' colour